# Where Can I get wordpress hosting similar to wordpress.com?

Tags: shared-hosting, hosting-recommendation

I know there are tons of places that offer wordpress hosting but what I am after is one where I dont need to do all the upgrades, patches, SQL admin etc. Basically I want it like wordpress.com where you create your blog and that's it. You blog and don't have to worry about the admin side. I don't mind paying.

Why I want this?
I am currently with wordpress.com but my site now has built up enough traffic that i want to start putting ads up which we all know isn't allowed on wordpress.com. this is why i want to move away from them now.

Comment: As there is no "right" answer to this question (many hosts are listed for personal preference), I'm converting this to a wiki question.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some popular companies that provide managed WordPress hosting, from highest to lowest price (starting packages):

- [WPEngine](http://wpengine.com/) (starting at $29/month)
- [Synthesis](http://websynthesis.com/) (starting at $27/month, for Genesis Framework users only)
- [ZippyKid](http://zippykid.com/pricing/) (starting at $25/month)
- [Page.ly](http://page.ly/) (starting at $19.95/month)

It is worth choosing a host who specialises in WordPress, in my opinion, especially if you like the ease of use of wordpress.com but want more flexibility to install plugins and themes.

I've been using ZippyKid for six months and have been really pleased with them.

Answer (score 0):

Search specifically for *managed* WordPress hosting. [Page.ly](http://page.ly/) is a popular one.

Answer (score 0):

Check out:

- [Grozota.com](http://www.grozota.com)

It's a specialized WordPress hosting for those who would like to have their website powered by WordPress but don't want to mess with anything...so they do all the job for their customers.

Their plans start at:

- Personal blog $4/month
- Landing page or a Website $14.99/month

Included with any subscription:

- 6 X Premium WordPress Themes
- 60 x Premium WordPress Plugins